# How to separate similar matching patterns

Tags: c#, regex

I want to analyse strings which can contain two different matching types.
The first type (I called it NC_Address) consists of one or more letters followed by (optional) white spaces and an integer or floating point number (no exponent required).
So valid expressions are for example

`G1`

`ang 17.3`

The second type (I called it Function_Call) consists of one ore more letters followed by (optional) white spaces and a pair of parenthesis which can enclose any substring.
Valid expressions therefore may be

`func ()`

`foo(,,7,z)`

I do this with the following code:

```
string pattern = @"(?<NC_Address>\s*[a-z]+\s*[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)|(?<Function_Call>[a-z]+\s*\(.*\)\s*)";            
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture;
MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(progLine, pattern, options);
```

This works as intended.

Now I would like to extend the range of admissible function names by including digits (and possible underscores). So I would like to have function names of the type
`func1 () or func2A(a, x, 5.2)`.

But names of this type collide with my first pattern.
However the difference is that in the case of a function name there will follow an opening parenthesis.

How can I use this knowledge and modify my matching pattern in order to avoid matching with my first matching type NC_Address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To also match underscore or digits, you can use `\w` and turn around the alternation to match the specific parts with the parenthesis first.

To match from an opening till closing parenthesis, you can use a negated character class `\([^()]*\)`

In the code you can now omit the `RegexOptions.Singleline` as there is no more dot in the pattern that could match a newline.

As you have used `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` you can omit the capture group in the `NC_Address`

```
(?<Function_Call>\w+\s*\([^()]*\))|(?<NC_Address>[a-z]+\s*[+-]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HAMkbt/1)

Comment: Sorry, this failed with`G1X0` which should be resolved as two matches with NC_Adress (`G1` and `X0`). Removing the two word boundary elements (\b) seems to do the job.

Comment: @Elec1 In that case you can omit the word boundaries. See https://regex101.com/r/HAMkbt/1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand everything but "NC_Address" can only end with digit and not a parenthesis right ?

So you can add a "$" to spécifie that "NC_Address" should end with digit.
This will not match with function that end with parentheses.

Like this : `(?<NC_Address>\s*[a-z]+\s*[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+$)`

Comment: NC_Address must not end with a digit. "X10." for example is a valid expression as "10." is a valid floating point number.